# AngularJS: How to prevent route change from happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web, angularjs-routing

I'm listening to the event `$routeChangeStart` and I want to be able to redirect the user to another controller based on a condition. I am able to visually redirect him to another controller with `$location.path()` but the original controller still gets called. How can I prevent it? `event.preventDefault()` doesn't work.

Comment: There is an open PR: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5714

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router if you haven't already. It has got a few much needed features that ngRoute doesn't have plus it doesn't have this bug.